# Attic Fan Exhaust Options

Tags: attic, exhaust-fan, soffit

I am looking to install an attic fan in my house (note: not a whole house fan). It was built in 2016 and is two story modular stucco, so no gable available for an exhaust window. I am reluctant to install one on the decking of my roof for obvious reasons, so I am left with only one real option and I can't find any literature to determine if there is an issue with it.

I want to mount the fan in the center of the attic and run it into some metal ventilation duct to the rear of the house and out a vent I install in the soffit. I realize this will be venting out of the soffit when the soffit is also where the outside air will be coming from, but the soffit runs the entire length of the roof underlayment so sucking back in the same hot air should be left to a minimum. I want to run it essentially as I would run a bathroom exhaust fan out my soffit. Does anyone see any issues with this plan?

Comment: It's really not difficult at all to properly flash a roof penetration. And if you do it where an exhaust fan should be (the peak of the roof) there's very little water to keep out, since no water runs down the roof to that location, so it's only got to shed direct rain, not the accumulated water flowing down the roof that a lower penetration has to shed.

Comment: Can you share those "obvious reasons"? They're not so obvious to everyone...

Comment: Sure. I am not crazy about cutting holes in the roof due to the potential for leaks and voiding of my roofs warranty. Also, if not cutting a hole in the roof then can perform all of the work myself if it is running ventilation duct. Otherwise I need to call out a company to do it for me. 

As to my actual question on my plan of action, any insight you may have as to any issues?

Comment: What is your goal with this fan install? It will help us to understand if this is a sensible plan of action or not.